# I only want to Display Author Link in authors bio

Tags: author

`the_author_link()` displays author name with hyperlink. I only want authors link to display and not authors name with hyperlink. how i suppose to do that?.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using this function :

```
get_the_author_meta('url')
```

You can see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_link/) the implementation of the function `get_the_author_link()` and you will see how they construct the link with name.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to print the URL of author, you can try this.

```
$authorLink = get_author_link();                
echo $authorLink;
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

**Updated** on 1st Nov,2017.

In my above solution, get_author_link() is deprecated for latest version of Wordpress.

You can get the any details of users by get_the_author_meta() method. 
In this function you need to pass the meta_key which you want to get.

Comment: this function is now deprecated in current WordPress version.